# How to make hot-wax-fluid simulation like on the example?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I can't figure out how to simulate hot wax.  I can adjust the fluid, but how do I do the cooling process?  When it falls to cool slightly, the consistency changes.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make a simulation like the example in the link: https://youtube.com/shorts/FRS4H3QuZAA?feature=share

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure that Blender can do it?

Comment: Hmm, not sure but hope

Comment: i think it is possible - with geometry nodes at least ;), and of course with animation nodes and sverchok as well

Comment: I playing around with it, but no results now

Comment: not sure how efficirent our sverchok will be in simulation. maybe GN suits most here